# Why is Flux Stone not generating?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

For some reason a lot of my new worlds don't generate Flux Stone. Not sure what I'm doing wrong, I've tried multiple different generation settings too. I feel like it might be when I go with (*Mineral Frequency* (**Everywhere**)). Anyone know for sure what causes flux stone to not generate?

Comment: did you search for flux pre embark

Comment: yes, I did a defined search after map creation.

Comment: Have you been fiddling with the raws? DF has the tendency to break in hilarious ways if you mess up.

Comment: i dont think so, i just do a normal make creation dont really like to get too crazy with the advanced parameters @kotekzot

Comment: i even reinstalled the game and whatnot, ive litarly created three worlds in a row with no flux stone present on the map @ratchet freak

Comment: If a fresh install doesn't generate flux then it's either a) the version is bugged, get a newer/older version or b) you're doing something wrong, possibly not searching properly.

Comment: @kotekzot well its not hard to search for flux all you gotta do is hit (yes) next to the flux stone preference

Comment: @Paralytic are you sure that search option works? I seem to recall some of those where bugged. Not 100% sure about that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have noticed this in the latest release too. I think the problem is that setting the Mineral Frequency to Everywhere makes the world generator go a little overboard with the minerals. It ends up replacing most of the flux stone with minerals. If you just go with a lower Mineral Frequency (I suggest Sparse or Frequent) you should get more Flux Stone.

Additionally there is a minor bug across numerous versions which causes the finder to not be able to find flux on "mineral everywhere" maps even when there is plenty. This has been tested, and after enough embarks you may get a feeling for the types of area which would have this material without requiring the finder.